# If the Stone-Čech compactification $\beta X$ of $X$ is connected then $X$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation, compactness, compactification

So I am searching to prove that if the Stone-Čech compactification $\beta X$ of a Tychonoff space $X$ is connected then $X$ is connected. Therefore, I tried to prove that $\beta[X]$ is connected and in particular I tried to procced as by reduction ad absurdum. So if $\beta[X]$ is not connected then there exist two disjoint set $A_1$ and $A_2$ of $\beta X$ such that $\beta[X]$ is disjoint union of $A_1\cap \beta[X]$ and $A_2\cap \beta[X]$. So I observed that
$$
\beta[X]\subseteq A_1\cup A_2
$$
and thus I conclude that $A_1\cup A_2$ is dense so that $X$ is union of $\operatorname{cl}A_1$ and $\operatorname{cl}A_2$ but this does not seem help; moreover I observed that
$$
(A_1\cap A_2)\cap\beta[X]=\emptyset
$$
so that by density of $X$ I clonclude that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint and thus
$$A_1\subseteq\beta X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A_2\quad\text{and}\quad A_2\subseteq\beta X\setminus\operatorname{cl} A_1
$$
and thus I conclude that $X$ is union of $X\setminus A_1$ and $X\setminus A_2$ so that $(X\setminus A_1)\cup (X\setminus A_2)$ is dense but another time this does not seem help.

Anyway, I know that a topological space $T$ is connected if and only if there not exists continuous function form $T$ to the discrete space $\{0,1\}$ so that I tried to define a function
$$
f(x):=\begin{cases}0,\,\text{if }x\in A_1\cap\beta[X]\\
1,\,\text{if }x\in A_2\cap\beta[X]\end{cases}
$$
for any $x\in\beta[X]$ and thus I tried to extend it to a continuous function on $\beta X$ but I unfortunately failed: however [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579049/stone-cech-compactification-and-connectedness) is said that this is a trivial fact but I really do not see this.

Finally, I tried to use the following hint given by my topology text.

> **Hint**: the clousure of a clopen set on $\beta[X]$ is clopen in $\beta X$.

However I was not able to use this hint and thus I thought to put a specific question. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Can you proofread your question? What is the distinction between $\beta[X]$ and $\beta X$?

Comment: @YuvalPeres $\beta[X]$ is the homeomorphic image of $X$ in $\beta X$ which is the  Stone-Čech compactification of $X$.

Comment: I see, I am used to just identifying that image with $X$. In any case this is confusing notation, maybe just call the homeomorphic image $[X]$ ?

Comment: Oh yeah! That's no problem to identify $X$ and $\beta[X]$ since they are homeomorphic. So could you help me?

Comment: The answer you linked to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579049/stone-cech-compactification-and-connectedness   seems good. The fact that continuous functions on $[X]$ extend to continuous functions on $\beta X$ is the defining property of $\beta X$.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Oh, perhaps I understood: do you  want mean that $\beta[X]$ is [$C$-embedded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189922/whats-the-meaning-of-c-embedded) into $\beta X$ with respect bounded function, right?

Comment: Which is called $C^*$ embedded in the link you gave. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification

Comment: @YuvalPeres Okay, thanks for your help: I completely forgot (what stupid!) that $\beta[X]$ is $C^*$ embedded into $\beta X$.

Comment: @YuvalPeres However, I have a little doubt: I know that a continuous and bounded function $f$ from $\beta[X]$ to $\Bbb R$ can be extended to a countinous function $\tilde f$ from $\beta X$ to $\Bbb R$ but this do not meand that $\varphi $ from $\beta[X]$ to $\{0,1\}$ can be extended to $\phi$ from $\beta X$ to $\{0,1\}$. So what can you say about?

Comment: By the density of the embedded copy $[X]$ in $\beta X$, the extension $\tilde f$ can only take the values $0,1$.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Oh this would really fine! Could you show this, please? Unfortunately FShrike's answer is overcomplicated so if you show this I would be grateful. Forgive the bother.

Comment: @YuvalPeres So I know that $\tilde f$ is continuous so that for any neighborhood of $V_{f(x)}$ with $x\in\beta X\setminus\beta[X]$ there exists a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that the inclusion $$\tilde f[U_x]\subseteq V_{f(x)}$$ holds. Now if $\beta[X]$ is dense in $\beta X$ then $U_x$ is **not** disjoint from $\beta[X]$ and thus there exist $y\in U_x\cap \beta[X]$ such that $\tilde f(y)=f(y)=0$ or such that $\tilde f(y)=f(y)=1$ but I do not see how this can help. So could you explain, please?

Comment: @YuvalPeres Oh yeah!!! Perhaps I understood: so if $f(x)\neq 0,1$ then I can choose $V_{f(x)}$ disjoint from $0$ and $1$ but $f[U_x]$ is never disjoint from $0$ and $1$ and so by this contradiction we conclude that necessarily $f(x)$ is $0$ or $1$ for any $x\in\beta X\setminus\beta[X]$ and so for any $x\in \beta X$, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A much less sophisticated argument:

> If $X$ is disconnected, there exists a non-constant continuous map $\varphi:X\to K$ where $K=\{0,1\}$ with the topology $\{\emptyset,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$. $K$ is trivially a compact Hausdorff space: by the universal property of the Stone-Cech compactification, there must exist a continuous map $\psi:\beta X\to K$ (forced to be non-constant by the conditions of the universal property) which forces $\beta X$ to be disconnected.

Comment: The formula *universal property* means that $\beta[X]$ is $C^*$-embedded into $\beta X$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Frankly? I don’t know. That very well may be an equivalent statement. However, the universal property is most simply stated in the form I state it here (and is the main one discussed if we view the Stone-Cech as left adjoint to the inclusion functor)

Comment: The formula *$\beta[X]$ is $C^*$-embedded into $\beta X$* means that any continuous and bounded function $f$ from $\beta[X]$ to $\Bbb R$ has a continuous extension to $\beta X$, that's all: it seems to me that your formula want indicate just this fact but obviously I cannot sure about.

Comment: Ah. Really stone cech is about displaying this for $[0,1]$ rather than $\Bbb R$ itself. See the Wiki article

Comment: Okay, so I image that by density of $\beta[X]$ you argue that the your continuous extension $\psi$ of $\varphi$ must be surjective and continuous map from $\beta X$ onto $\{0,1\}$ because on this set the subspace euclidean topology is the discrete topology, right? That is substantially the reason for which $\psi$ is continuous and surjective onto $\{0,1\}$ are that showed above into the comments, right?

Comment: I’m not actually arguing anything as complicated as that. I just simply use the universal property! Because the intermediary function $\psi$ must agree with $\varphi$ on $\eta_X(X)$, it must be non-constant. @AntonioMariaDiMauro

Comment: Of course the question of why the universal property holds is much more complicated, but I hope you’refamiliar with such proof if you know about Stone-Cech. If you’re not, the topological aspects of my other answer (linked) are sufficient

Comment: So I proved that if $X$ is Tychonoff then $\beta[X]$ is $C^*$-embedded into $\beta X$ and it seem to me you are calling this fact universal property perhaps because it can explained using Cathegory Theory results which unfortunately I cannot undersand having not studied Cathegory Theory.

Comment: Indeed when you state that "$\psi$ must agree with $\phi$ on $\eta_X[X]$" I explain this using the result I summarised in the last comment whereas it seem you did it differently.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro “Universal property” is a category theory word, but no knowledge of this theory is required. It can be very succinctly described, see e.g. the relevant section of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification). I will restate it: “for every compact Hausdorff $K$ and every continuous $\varphi:X\to K$, there exists a unique continuous $\psi:\beta X\to K$ such that $\varphi=\psi\circ\eta_X$.” This is really the important thing about Stone-Cech, and characterises it uniquely (as a compact Hausdorff space). All other properties follow from this

Comment: I am very stupid: indeed the day before yesterday I proved what now you stated but unfortunately lately I am a bit under pression and so due to swiftness I forgot this **relevant** fact so that I thanks you very much to have remembered it to me. So answer unvoted and approved: thanks moreover for your kindness. See you soon.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro You’re welcome! Cheers

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro You might also want to use a similar approach to prove the following: for any topological space $X$, $X$ is connected if and only if $\beta X$ is connected. The proof of this just occurred to me, is why I mentioned it

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand: you exactly answer to this question with the present answer.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I showed $\beta X$ is connected implies $X$ is connected, not the converse

Comment: Oh yeah: you wrote "if and only if" right!

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is not connected, there are nonempty open $U,V$ which disconnect $X$. $\varphi:X\to[0,1]$, $\varphi|_U\equiv0$ and $\varphi|_V\equiv1$ is continuous.

I use the construction of:

> Let $\eta_X:X\to[0,1]^{C(X,[0,1])}$, $x\mapsto(f(x))_{f\in C(X,[0,1])}$, where $[0,1]^{C(X,[0,1])}$ has the product topology. Let $\beta X:=\overline{\eta_X(X)}$ with the subspace topology, and $\pi_f:\beta X\to[0,1]$ the projection maps for each $f\in C(X,[0,1])$.

Then in particular, $\mathcal{O}_1:=\beta X\cap\pi_{\varphi}^{-1}\{[0,1/2)\}$ and $\mathcal{O}_2:=\beta X\cap\pi_{\varphi}^{-1}\{(1/2,0]\}$ are both open in $\beta X$. To check whether or not $\mathcal{O}_1\sqcup\mathcal{O}_2=\beta X$ we need only check this on $\pi_{\varphi}(\beta X)$. It can be shown that each $x$ in this set must lie in the closure of $\varphi(X)$, which is $\varphi(X)=\{0\}\sqcup\{1\}$ itself. Therefore $\mathcal{O}_1\cap\mathcal{O}_2=\emptyset$ (and each set is obviously nonempty) and each element $\zeta$ of $\beta X$ is in exactly one of these sets since $\pi_{\varphi}(\zeta)\in\overline{\varphi(X)}=\{0,1\}$ must hold, and these points are covered by the $\mathcal{O}_{1,2}$.

This shows that $X$ disconnected implies $\beta X$ disconnected (no further hypotheses on the topology of $X$), so $\beta X$ connected must imply $X$ is connected.

If you want me to expand on why each $x\in\pi_{\varphi}(\beta X)$ must lie in $\overline{\varphi(X)}$, I will add this.

Addition:

> In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4469692/815585) self-answer I prove that for all topological spaces $X$, all compact Hausdorff spaces $K$ and all continuous $\varphi:X\to K$, we have a unique continuous $\psi:\beta X\to K$ with $\psi\circ\eta_X\equiv\varphi$ (universal property) *and* the related fact that we must have $\pi_{h\circ\varphi}(b)\in h^{-1}\overline{\varphi(X)}$ for all $b\in\beta X$ and all $h\in C(K,[0,1])$.
>
> As $K=[0,1]$ is the space I took here, with $\varphi$ being the constant restrictions on $U,V$ in the rest of this post, I may let $h=\mathrm{id}_K$ and claim that for all $b\in\beta X$, $\pi_{\mathrm{id}_K\circ\varphi}(b)\in(\mathrm{id}_K)^{-1}\overline{\varphi(X)}$, that is, $\pi_{\varphi}(b)\in\overline{\varphi(X)}$ must hold.

I add the relevant portion of the answer here for convenience:

> Fix $b\in\beta X=\overline{\eta_X(X)}$, and take any continuous $h:K\to[0,1]$. There are different ways to go about the following, but we may as well use a sequence as that is the "nice" way. For all $n\in\Bbb N$ let $F_n=[b(h\circ\varphi)-1/n,b(h\circ\varphi)+1/n]\cap[0,1]$. As $h$ is continuous, $h^{-1}\{F_n\}$ is closed and thus compact in $K$; moreover, $h^{-1}\{F_{n+1}\}\subseteq h_0^{-1}\{F_n\}$ always.
>
> By the product topology, we can take a basic, cylinder-set neighbourhood of $b$ on the coordinate $h\circ\varphi$ and the nonempty open set $F_n^{\circ}$ for each $n$. As $\eta_X(X)$ is dense in $\beta X$, this neighbourhood of $b$ will contain some $\eta_X(x_n)$ for some $x_n\in X$, thus $\eta_X(x_n)(h\circ\varphi)=h(\varphi(x_n))\in F_n^{\circ}$.
>
> That guarantees $h^{-1}\{F_n\}$ is never empty, as it contains $\varphi(x_n)$. By the finite intersection property and compactness, $A_h:=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}h^{-1}\{F_n\}$ is a nonempty compact subset of $K$. Each element $a\in A_h$ is such that $h(a)$ is in all the $F_n$; by basic properties of $[0,1]$ we must then have that $h(a)=b(h\circ\varphi)$ for all $a\in A_h$. We can also note that $a\in\overline{\varphi(X)}$.
>
> Take these nonempty compact $A_h$ for all continuous $h:K\to[0,1]$. We want to show that their intersection is nonempty, since the intersection is necessarily a one-point set (if it is nonempty) by the Urysohn lemma. We can assert a nonempty intersection if we demonstrate the finite intersection property. Let $\{h_i\}_{i=1}^k\subset C(K,[0,1])$ be arbitrary - we want to show $\bigcap_{i=1}^kA_{h_i}\neq\emptyset$. Let, for $1\le i\le k$ and $n\in\Bbb N$, $F^{(i)}_{n}:=[b(h_i\circ\varphi)-1/n,b(h_i\circ\varphi)+1/n]\cap[0,1]$. Similarly can we construct basic cylinder neighbourhoods of $b$, for fixed $n$, by asserting the neighbourhood $(F^{(i)}_n)^{\circ}$ on the coordinates $h_i\circ\varphi$. By density will this contain an $\eta_X(x_n)$ for some $x_n\in X$, with $h_i(\varphi(x_n))\in(F^{(i)}_n)^{\circ}$ for all $i$. Then the intersected preimage $B_n:=\bigcap_{i=1}^kh_i^{-1}\{F^{(i)}_n\}$ is nonempty (and compact by continuity of each $h_i$) for each $n$, with the same property $B_{n+1}\subseteq B_n$ for all $n$. We have by the finite intersection property: $$\emptyset\neq\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}B_n\subseteq\bigcap_{i=1}^kA_{h_i}$$Which concludes the proof: $$\exists!a_b\in\bigcap_{h\in C(K,[0,1])}h^{-1}b(h\circ\varphi),\,\forall b\in\beta X$$It is pleasing to observe that this $a_b$ is in the closure $\overline{\varphi(X)}$ always, and can be intuitively thought of as a limit point of the $\eta_X(x)$ approaching $b$.

Comment: Hi, I read your answer. So I do not really understand your argumentations about disjointness of $\cal O_1$ and $\cal O_2$ but I see that thy are disjoint because $\pi^{-1}_\varphi\{[0,1/2]\}$ and $\pi^{-1}_\varphi\{(1/2,0\]\}$ are disjoint -provided this is true; however I do not really understand why $\beta X$ is union of $\cal O_1$ and $\cal O_2$. Finally I know that a space $T$ is disconnected if and only if there exists a continuous function $g$ form $T$ to the discrete space $\{0,1\}$ but now $\varphi$ is on $[0,1]$ and not on $\{0,1\}$ so that I ask clarification about.

Comment: So could you explain better, please?

Comment: Hi I will answer comments shortly @AntonioMariaDiMauro I use $\eta_X$ notation deliberately (category theory!)

Comment: Do not worry: I only edited the answer because I use the letter $\beta$ to denote the embedding but if you prefer the letter $\eta$ that's no problem.

Comment: $\varphi$ is a continuous map $X\to\{0,1\}$ sure, but it is also continuous as a map $\varphi:X\to[0,1]$. This fact allows me to do two things: I can use $\varphi$ *as a coordinate* in the $\beta X$ product space, and it also allows me to claim $\pi_{\varphi}(\beta X)\subseteq\overline{\varphi(X)}$ (which comes from a proof involving the universal property, I will expand on that point if you wish).

Comment: Since $\varphi$ is a coordinate, I can use product topology basic open sets about the coordinate $\varphi$, so I create the open nonempty sets $\mathcal{O}_{1,2}$. They are disjoint precisely because their projections on $\pi_{\varphi}$ are disjoint, but my point is that any $x=(x_f)_{f\in C(X,[0,1])}\in\beta X$ **must** have $\pi_{\varphi}(x)\in\overline{\varphi(\beta X)}$ by previously mentioned points (--> therefore in one of the $O$ sets)

Comment: Oaky, so could you explain why the inclusion $$\pi_\varphi(\beta X)\subseteq\overline{\varphi(X)}$$ holds, please?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I've explained it. The explainer links back to a previous post I made. **You can ignore the category theory**, just focus on the topological aspects of my answer (indeed that whole post was about topological solutions and interpretations in the place of category theory)

Comment: I tried to read your question and answer but unfortunately I do not understand the formalism and unfortunately this is a big problem to me, sorry.

Comment: Could perhaps implement the Yuval Peres hint? I think it is more simple to me.

Comment: The formalism can be largely ignored in my answer (you may ignore the question entirely). Please read the final greyed out paragraph in my answer, it is pure topology @AntonioMariaDiMauro

Comment: The relevant part of the answer (pure topology) is now included in this post. I don't emphasise it, but by following my proof and little remarks here and there you can see why this point $\pi_{h\circ\varphi}(b)$ must be in the closure of $\varphi(X)$ (it is constructed from topological limits). I also use the notation $b(f)=\pi_f(b)$, interpreting elements of $\beta X$ as functions